# Implement subitem in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

How could I implement a sub item where the item would have a parent to that of the same item. For example, I have a database that holds tasks/todos. Each todo has a title(`TEXT`), completed(`INTEGER` [1 if true, 0 if false]), and due date(`TEXT`) column. I would like to add functionality to have subtasks, where a task could possibly have a parent task. How would I implement this in SQLite for Android? **NOT IN SQL!** So no foreign keys (triggers are allow, though)! Could I just have a separate table (subtask) and have a foreign key trigger to link subtask(`INTEGER parent`) to task(`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT _id`)? Or should I add a column to my original task table(`INTEGER parent`)? How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the last thought of yours. Modify your original table by adding column "parnent" and store ID of the parent task.

Creating another table just for sub-tasks wouldn't be the best solution. what will you do if your sub-task will have sub-tasks of it's own?